# TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y'

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

Not sure why my code is not compiling here. I have properly defined the property `s`.

Here is the code:

```
export class FiniteSet<T> extends MathSet<T> {

  private s: Set<T>;

  constructor(values: Array<T>) {
    super();
    this.s = new Set(values);
  }
```

(MathSet is an abstract class without any properties)

When running I get this error on every line with `this.s`:

`TS2339: Property 's' does not exist on type 'FiniteSet'.`

I looked at some other posts with similar issues, however, they all seem to be related to interface properties instead of class properties.
I have noticed that using `this["s"]` works however I'm not a huge fan.

Are there any fixes?

Comment: Well, what is `MathSet`?

Comment: It is just an abstract class. `s` is not defined in there

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this... https://tsplay.dev/w2zK9w

Comment: HmmI. have other methods in the class that I did not show, however, I would doubt that they would cause an issue.

Comment: So what can we do here if this isn't a [mre]?  Do you want to try to [edit] the code in the question to demonstrate the issue you're seeing?